# How do you get an RFID reader to work with Raspberry Pi 3 and UWP?

Tags: serial, uart, rfid, c#

everyone!
This question is in relation to my Raspberry Pi 3 and Windows 10 IoT Core project. I intend to use an RFID Reader (short range only), along with an universal windows application,  plugged to the RPi using USB to UART, and want to receive the unique code of the card that comes into its range. 
I've found a few sample projects, some on hackster.io, however, the code asks for a uartBridgeName, that I don't have any idea on where to find.
I've tried checking device manager > Ports, and have tried using the name of the UART Serial Controller that appears there, but to no avail.
If anyone could be able to help, I'd appreciate it greatly.
Projects I've tried working on so far:
https://www.hackster.io/careypayette/long-range-uhf-rfid-item-tracking-system-fc5372
And...
https://www.hackster.io/homeworld/rfid-register-1c9393

I'm new to UWP apps and RPis, so kindly guide me.
Thanks!